# Add elements of unknown list length - Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I seem to be struggling a little with this issue. Let's say you have a list of various lengths i.e:

```
first_list = [8, 7, 5, 1, 2, 4]
```

or

```
second_list = [6, 8, 4, 1]
```

regardless of how long or short the list is how would you be able to add the elements of each list such that all the elements get added together? I.e `First` > `first + second` > `first + second + third` > `...` etc

```
first_list = [8, 8+7, 8+7+5, 8+7+5+1, 8+7+5+1+2, 8+7+5+1+2+4]

second_list = [6, 6+8, 6+8+4, 6+8+4+1]
```

I have tried a few different things but just don't seem to be able to do this :-/

Comment: The computation that you are trying to do involves just a single list. Why did you even mention two lists? In any event, what have you tried and where are you stuck? What are some of the "few different things" that you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1,len(myList)):
    myList[i] += myList[i-1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkSnyder! So simple & so compact! Beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = [8, 7, 5, 1, 2, 4]
>>> [sum(my_list[:i+1]) for i in range(len(my_list))]
[8, 15, 20, 21, 23, 27]
```

Note that even though this *looks* more compact, @MarkSnyder's answer is actually more performant as it has a time complexity of `O(n)` while this one is `O(n^2)`.

**Edit:** If you are using Python 3.8 or higher, you can use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) to have a list comprehension with `O(n)` complexity:

```
>>> my_list = [8, 7, 5, 1, 2, 4]
>>> s = 0
>>> [s := s + i for i in my_list]
[8, 15, 20, 21, 23, 27]
```

Comment: A decent one-linear, but the problem with this approach is that it has quadratic complexity. Unlikely to be of any real significance, but it is suboptimal to repeatedly add the same numbers when one addition is enough

Comment: Thank you @Selcuk even more compact :-) Not sure what you mean @JohnColeman?

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right, I should have mentioned that. Edited my answer.

Comment: @Jo3Dirt It means that this answer is shorter but slower. It won't matter if your lists are short, but not the optimal solution in any way.

Comment: @Jo3Dirt The repeated summing over increasingly longer slices makes this an example of a [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). It is unlikely to matter here, but it isn't bad to at least be aware of the fact that Python one-liners sometimes feature an implicit elegance vs. efficiency trade-off. (In this case, the efficiency probably makes it worth while, so (+1))

Comment: @JohnColeman It is possible to have more efficient list comprehensions using the walrus operator in Python 3.8. I am not a big fan of this feature but added to my answer for reference.

Comment: @Selcuk Cool. I didn't know about that operator. The need to initialize `s` prior to the comprehension makes it seem less elegant, and its reliance on side effects makes it less functional. But, it is more efficient.

Comment: @JohnColeman That operator is all about side effects, that's why I'm not a fan. I'm sure one can find a way to eliminate the need to initialise `s` (use `my_list[0]`?). I am leaving that part as an exercise for the readers.